Why does adding heat to the subsonic flow increase the speed of the flow?
In Rayleigh flow, adding heat to the subsonic flow increases the speed and adding heat to the supersonic flow decreases the speed.
But what is its physical cause?

First, keep in mind that Rayleigh flow only applies to a constant area duct.  It is a model of flow in an inviscid pipe with constant area.  Second, adding heat does not increase/decrease the speed -- it increases or decreases the Mach number.  This generally works out the same, but the speed of sound is also changing as you add heat in Rayleigh flow.  Here are some nice online notes https://kyleniemeyer.github.io/gas-dynamics-notes/compressible-flows/heat-transfer.html

but adding heat increases velocity as well as mach number at the same time !

Indeed.  Fundamentally, adding heat is adding energy.  The acceleration subsonically isn't very mysterious -- it is the drive towards choked flow supersonically that is the real wild part.  It is worth making sure you understand choked flow in a converging-diverging nozzle (no heat or friction) before moving to Rayleigh or Fanno flows.

I'm not trying to be mysterious or tricky.  @sophit Unfortunately, I don't remember enough of it to give an intuitive explanation.  My gas dynamics classes were more than 25 years ago and I remember it seeming like magic at the time.  I don't really know that I had a true understanding of this one -- it may have been something that I just accepted (and never had the time/opportunity to revisit later).  I remember that choking in a variable area duct came first...

Let's take as an example the brayton cycle, as used in turbojets.
in the combustor section, heat is added to the flow by burning fuel in it at constant pressure. Adding heat to the flow makes it want to expand and occupy more volume. Now since the mass flow rate entering the engine is the same as that leaving the engine (conservation of mass), and since the exhaust occupies more volume than the intake, it is necessary for the exhaust flow to exit the engine going faster than the intake flow.
This in turn means that the momentum of the flow entering the engine is different (less than) the momentum contained in the exhaust flow. A time change in momentum has the units of a force; in this case that force is the thrust of the engine.

Adding heat to a subsonic flow increases the speed of the flow because it increases the temperature of the gas molecules, causing them to move faster and thereby increasing the velocity of the flow. This is governed by the ideal gas law, where an increase in temperature leads to an increase in the kinetic energy of the molecules, resulting in higher velocity.

So why doesn't that also apply to supersonic flow?

"Adding heat to a subsonic flow increases the speed of the flow because it increases the temperature of the gas molecules, increasing the velocity of the flow" That's not correct. Higher kinetic energy only means that each molecules is moving faster but that has nothing to do with the average speed of the whole molecules, average speed which might well be zero. If you heat up you oven, the air inside it does not become supersonic, it just stay there where it is no matter the temperature... "This is governed by the ideal gas law" In that law there is no velocity given...
